И снова fetch promise в JS
Есть такой вот код:
const getData = () =>
      fetch(apiUrl,{
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            cache: "no-cache",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            redirect: "follow",
            referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
            body: JSON.stringify(d),
          }).then((response) =>
        response.json()
      );
    
    const dataPromise = getData();    
    dataPromise.then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });

Нужно вытащить result "наружу". Как это сделать в "ванильном" JS?

наружа.result = result

Ну а вообще дубликат: Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания

С чем у вас возникли сложности и что есть наружа? Поидее ваш код должен в консоли отображать полученный результат.

async function fetchData() {
try {
const result = await getData();
console.log(result);
return result;
} catch (error) {
console.error("Ошибка получения данных:", error);
}
}

@andreymal наружа.result = result я делал с массивом. результат был обнадёживающим, но.. нет. в массиве был элемент с индексом 0 в котором были нужные данные, но при попытке к ним обратиться они оказывались undefined. Насчёт дубликата: jQuery и фреймворки использовать нельзя. Помещать результат в поля формы, а потом его извлекать... ну, такое себе.

@Owlly после вызова fetchData() я получаю всё тот же Promise. Promise { : "pending" } ​ : "fulfilled" ​ : Object { id: 1, jsonrpc: "2.0", result: (18) […] } ​ : Promise.prototype { … } и остаётся вопрос как извлечь 

@SwaD Так он и отображается. Он мне нужен за пределами getData

@vladvisitor «при попытке к ним обратиться» — значит вы обращались к ним слишком рано, забыв дождаться получения ответа от сервера. А зачем вы начали приплетать «jQuery и фреймворки», вообще непонятно

Все зависит от реализации. Можно "наружу" обернуть в фукнцию и ее вызывать, когда пришел ответ. Можно дальше в цепочке .then обрабатывать данные, можно попробовать всю логику обернуть в асинхронную фукнцию и там дожидаться ответа с помощью await и обрабатывать полученные данные. Т.е. вариантов много, но что из этого подойдет вам, надо смотреть уже по коду.

fetchData().then((result) => {
console.log(result); // Результат доступен здесь
}).catch((error) => {
console.error("Ошибка:", error);
});

let naruja = {};

    //------------------------------
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", apiUrl, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            naruja.response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(d));
    //------------------------------


    console.log(naruja.response) 

если без fetch,
и если не критично использование синхронного запроса,
то так работает

Твой код выведет undefined... Поскольку присвоение naruja.response будет "потом", после твоего консольного вывода. ;)

@ksa У нас теперь синхронный запрос. В нём нету "сейчас" и "потом". Всё работает. xhr.open("POST", apiUrl, true); - вот тогда - да

Минус за синхронный запрос

Вместо синхронного запроса, лучше реструктурировать код так, что бы он мог работать с асинхронными вызовами.

@SwaD Лучше. Вопросов нет. Как? Для того я и задавал вопрос. Вставлять код, в котором могут быть ещё аналогичные запросы за then((response) => { - не вариант. Использовать элементы DOM и localStorage - тоже.

@vladvisitor во-первых, почему не вариант? Во-вторых, существование async/await вы принципиально игнорируете?

@andreymal Как-то так? `async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {
const response = await fetch(url, {
method: "POST",
mode: "cors",
cache: "no-cache",
credentials: "same-origin",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
redirect: "follow",
referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
return await response.json();
}
var n = [];
var c = postData(apiUrl, d).then((data) => {
n.push(data);
});
console.log(n)` - ну то же самое.

@vladvisitor и опять вы не дождались завершения запроса перед вызовом console.log

@andreymal Ну, ок. Подождал `var n = [];
var c = postData(apiUrl, d).then((data) => {
n.push(data);
});
var m = [];
setTimeout(function(){
m = n;
//console.log(n)
},2000)
console.log(m)` - результат не изменился

@vladvisitor в одном console.log дождались (наверное), в другом console.log не дождались

Сейчас не понятно, как и где вы хотите использовать полученный ответ. И уже от этого надо подбирать решение.

@SwaD Аналогично приведённому синхронному запросу

в лоб - не получится. Сначал выполнится синхронная часть скрипта, а уже затем стартанут асинхронные обработчики

Использование синхронных запросов валит предупреждения в консоль и тормозит загрузку страницы. Этот способ отправки запросов устарел.

@SwaD в лоб - не получится. То есть самое очевидное - переделать код как-то так: `dataPromise.then((result) => {
myNextPartOfCode(result)
); и забыть? Ну, совсем не хочется. Но если нет - так нет.

@aepot именно поэтому я и задал вопрос

Да, примерно так и надо переписать
